# Showing complete 24hr time display (00:00:00)

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

I have a basic script to display PST time based on 24:00hr UTC clock. Everything is working fine except it only displays 0:00:00 (h:m:s) for hours 0-9am and I want to have an extra 0 as a prefix (ex: 00:00:00).

My script is:

```
function startTime() {
  const today = new Date();
  let h = today.getUTCHours()-8;
  let m = today.getUTCMinutes();
  let s = today.getUTCSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
```

I tried adding the following with no such luck:

```
function checkTime(h) {
  if (h < 10) {h = "0" + h};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return h;
}
```

Comment: In your snippets you forgot to call `h = checkTime(h);` but only did it for `m` and `s`.

Comment: This won't work where the UTC hour is less than 8. Say if it's 7 then instead of 23 you'll get -1, and calling *checkTime* will return "0-7". Most places that observe PST also observe daylight saving so the offset isn't always -8.

Comment: @AndrewParks I want to show PST time for every user no matter where they are. The -8 offset is working fine, the only missing detail is the missing 0 for 0-9.

Comment: There is a new way of doing this with JavaScript, look up "Intl.DateTimeFormat" on MDM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `en-GB` locale displays half-past midnight as 00:30:00, but the `en-US` locale displays it as 24:30:00.

```js
const today = new Date();
const time = today.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', 
  {timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles', hour12: false})
console.log(time)
```

Comment: en-GB and en-US are **languages**, specifically BCP47 language tags. Also Los Angeles observes daylight saving so for about half the year the result is Pacific Daylight Time (PDT), not PST. ;-)

Comment: @RobG interesting - please could you clarify? The docs say the "locales" argument to  toLocaleTimeString  is "A string with a BCP 47 language tag, or an array of such strings. Corresponds to the locales parameter of the Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor." I'm not sure how to interpret their mixing together of the terms 'locale' and 'language tag'. https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date/tolocaletimestring

Comment: The use of "locale" is a misnomer. As far as I can tell, it was introduced by the authors of ECMA-402. As you note, the parameter is called "locale" but is in fact a language tag. I can't find any dictionary anywhere that includes a concept of language in the meaning of the word locale.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to call `h = checkTime(h);`

```js
function startTime() {
  const today = new Date();
  let h = today.getUTCHours()-8;
  let m = today.getUTCMinutes();
  let s = today.getUTCSeconds();
  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}

function checkTime(h) {
  if (h < 10) {h = "0" + h};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return h;
}
startTime();
```

```html
<div id="txt"></div>
```